# Why are type declarations required in this Scala implementation of foldLeft

Tags: scala

I had tried to implement a foldLeft on a LinkedList with this code, one curried foldLeft2, and one not, foldLeft:

```
sealed trait LinkedList[+E] {
  @tailrec
  final def foldLeft[A](accumulator: A, f: (A, E) => A): A = {
    this match {
      case Node(h, t) => {
        val current = f(accumulator, h)
        t.foldLeft(current, f)
      }
      case Empty => accumulator
    }
  }
  @tailrec
  final def foldLeft2[A](accumulator: A)(f: (A, E) => A): A = {
    this match {
      case Node(h, t) => {
        val current = f(accumulator, h)
        t.foldLeft2(current)(f)
      }
      case Empty => accumulator
    }
  }
}
```

But when I use foldLeft, it seems I need to declare the type for accumulator and item, but for foldLeft2, I don't. Can someone explain why that is?

```
class LinkedListSpecification extends Specification {
  "linked list" should {
    "foldLeft correctly" in {
      val original = LinkedList(1,2,3,4)
      original.foldLeft(0, (acc: Int, item: Int) => acc + item) === 10
    }
  }
  "linked list" should {
    "foldLeft2 correctly" in {
      val original = LinkedList(1,2,3,4)
      original.foldLeft2(0)((acc, item) => acc + item) === 10
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the type inference in Scala works left-to-right across parameter lists.
Thus in the second version `foldLeft2` it is able to infer the type A as `Int` before it continues to the next parameter list where it now expects a function `(Int,E)=>Int`. 
While in the first version `foldLeft` it is trying to infer `A` at the same time by both parameters (`accumulator` and `f`). It complains about the anonymous function you are passing to it because it hasn't inferred type `A` yet.

Comment: That seems correct. And I am able to remove the type declaration  from item in the first test, and it still compiles. Thanks for the clarification on that.